# How to Create Group description[About Field or aboutMe property] in AEM programatically?

Tags: java, servlets, aem, sling

I wrote a java program to create a Group inside AEM. It is working fine. But along with `Group` I also need to create another Group `aboutMe` property.

My code:

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
UserManager userManager = ((JackrabbitSession) session).getUserManager();
JackrabbitSession js = (JackrabbitSession) session;
Group group = null;
group = userManager.createGroup("TestGroup");
session.save();
```

Is there any way to add aboutMe property field also?

Answer (score 0):

You could do `group.setProperty("jcr:description","your string")` or for that matter any property. Refer to javadocs [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/security/user/Authorizable.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20javax.jcr.Value))

**Update**

Add dependency to your project pom for `com.adobe.granite.security.user`

Inject

```
  @Reference
  private UserPropertiesService service;
```

Get UserProperties Object (resource is the resource instance to your Group) -

```
if (this.service != null) {
        Authorizable authorizable = (Authorizable)resource.adaptTo(Authorizable.class);
        UserProperties userProperties;
        if (authorizable == null)
        {
          UserProperties userProperties = (UserProperties)resource.adaptTo(UserProperties.class);
          if (userProperties != null) {
            UserManager uMgr = (UserManager)resolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);
            authorizable = uMgr.getAuthorizable(userProperties.getAuthorizableID());
          }

        }
        else
        {
          Session session = ((Node)resource.adaptTo(Node.class)).getSession();
          UserPropertiesManager mgr = this.service.createUserPropertiesManager(session, resolver);
          String propPath = request.getParameter("path");
          userProperties = mgr.getUserProperties(authorizable, propPath);
        }
```

Once you get the UserProperties, you can add the `aboutMe` information to your group.

For further reference, read [this](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/security/user/servlets/UserPropertiesServlet.html) and the javadocs [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/security/user/UserProperties.html)

Comment: description means [About] field ? not a group node description. its a group profile

Comment: @HaninJazi - Refer to my updates above. The long way of doing it :)